# Can we use infix generic methods in Kotlin ?

Tags: generics, kotlin, infix-notation

Compiler accept infix+generic methods, but what is the syntax to use it ?
Example, given those 2 identical methods (modulo arbitrary generic type) :

```
infix inline fun Int1.plus1(i: Int1) = Int1(this.value + i.value)
infix inline fun <U> Int1.plus2(i: Int1) = Int1(this.value + i.value)
```

I can write :

```
Int1(3).plus1(Int1(4))
Int1(3) plus1 Int1(4)
Int1(3).plus2<Int>(Int1(4))
```

but this call is invalid :

```
Int1(3) plus2<Int> Int1(4)
```

Someone can explain me why ?

Answer (score 5):

TL;DR yes, we can

First, there's no point in parameterizing such method

```
infix fun <U> Int.foo(i: Int) = ...
```

because **foo** never use type parameter **U**, both caller and arguments types are defined

When you parameterize a method you connect a type from it's [signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_signature) with generic parameter like

```
infix fun <U> U.foo (other: U) = ...
```

or at least one of them

```
infix fun <U> Int.foo (other: U) = ...
infix fun <U> U.foo (other: Int) = ...
```

Compiler will guess type of **U** by argument and/or caller object types

In your case compiler can't guess **U** type because it's not connected neither to caller nor to argument

Comment: But lets say you have a class `Int2` that extends `Int1`. Then you have this function: `infix inline fun <reified U> U.print(i: Int) = println("${U::class} $i")`. If you want `U` to be `Int1`, you can call it like this: `Int2(5).print<Int1>(4)`. Is it possible to do this call using infix notation?

Comment: @marstran Yes, you have to cast it's argument to expected type

`Int2(5) print 4.to(Int1::class)`

Comment: That doesn't work. That argument is a normal `Int`. It's the receiver of type `U` which is the problem. Would I have to cast that instead? Seems a little weird that I have to use a cast only when dealing with infix functions.

Comment: @marstran sorry, I misunderstand you but now I think I get it: you want
`Int2(5).print<Int1>(4)` to print `Int1 4` right? So you have to cast caller to `Int1` type: `(Int2(5) as Int1) print 4`

Comment: That's right. :) I find it weird that I can't write it like `Int2(5) print<Int1> 4` though. Kinda seems like a workaround to do the cast.

Comment: Not at all. If methods `Int1#print` and `Int2#print` are different (if not, why do you want explicitly pass `Int1`?) and you want `Int2#print` work like `Int1#print` but for `Int2` argument, I'd say it's conceptual problem

Comment: But if I take the example one step further (it does get kinda ridiculous now though). How can you call this function using infix notation? `infix inline fun <reified U> Int.print(i: Int) = println("$this ${U::class} $i")`. Calling it using normal notation works fine: `5.print<String>(4)` prints `5 class kotlin.String 4`.

Comment: thank you for the interesting replies!
marstran you are in aligned with my question : my initial question was a bit wierd because <U> was unused... but you must imagine it is the case :) but U do not appears in signature

Comment: It can make sense to parameterize a function with a type that isn't used in the input parameters, just in the return type. For example, I'd like to have an infix fun for `com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath#read`, which takes two strings but returns a generic type (it's casting the result to the specified type). It seems such a fun cannot be called with infix notation.